# Comment = vote to off-topic

Tags: discussion

I wrote

> Hi! This question is about an economic issue, but not the academic discipline of economics, and as such it is off-topic here.

under a question as a comment, then went to vote to close it as off-topic, but the question already had my close vote! Is there a script that looks for "is off-topic here" or something similar in comments and then creates a vote to close (when commenter is eligible)? If yes, what are the exact terms that trigger this?

---

Update: 
It is possible that I was out of my mind that day and forgot that I voted to close before writing the comment, because I tried to reproduce the phenomenon and was not successful.

Comment: And also the close vote is against Problematic Homework Question, which isn't really the issue in this case.